# Capture Marathon event notifications from Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

We need to capture Marathon Application events at various places in our application architecture (Nginx for generating conf files, UI updates in frontend  when a marathon app is restarting etc.) Presently, we are polling /v2/apps/{appID} endpoint to be aware of things. But I don't think that is the best approach to go.

So far, I am planning to replace that with /v2/events stream or /v2/eventSubscriptions callback functionalities but I was kind of more inclined to fetch these updates from Zookeeper instead, to have a consistent and common source of such information in future. As of now, I am not really sure if Zookeeper has such event updates etc pushed into it by Marathon that could be subscribed. If yes, could you please direct me to appropriate documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

The events are not stored in the persistent store (zookeeper). You can query the current state of all applications via the `/v2/apps` endpoint and then attach to the `/v2/events` stream endpoint to get notified about all changes to that state. See the [REST API](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html) Documentation.